# Azure AD AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf

Tags: .net, angular, .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I need to be able to acquire a token on behalf of a user in my API, using the token I received in my client angular app. I have used MSAL package in angular to get the token from my client app registration in Azure. I have saved this into my database, so when my azure function runs, it can read this token to acquire a new token from the API app registration in Azure. Then I need to read the mailbox of the user.

So far I can get the token in angular like so:

```
this.msalService.acquireTokenPopup({
      scopes: [
        "api://*******************/access_as_user", // permission to access API App Registration
        "Mail.ReadWrite"
      ],
      prompt: "consent",
      authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common",
    })
      .subscribe({
        next: (response: any) => {
          var graphTokenDto: MicrosoftGraphDto = {
            accessToken: response.accessToken,
            expires: new Date(response.expiresOn).toISOString(), // Time to timestamp
            scopes: response.scopes,
            status: MicrosoftGraphStatus.Connected,
            tokenType: response.tokenType,
            username: response.account.username,
            idToken: response.idToken
          }
          this.userService.connectMailAccount(graphTokenDto);

        },
        error: (error: any) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      })
```

**Acquiring token in .NET Api**

```
_settings = settings;

            IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(_settings.ClientId)
                .WithClientSecret(_settings.ClientSecret)
                .WithTenantId(_settings.TenantId)
                .Build();

            UserAssertion userAssertion = new UserAssertion(microsoftGraphToken.AccessToken);

            var scopes = microsoftGraphToken.Scopes.AsEnumerable();

            AuthenticationResult result = await app.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf(scopes, userAssertion)
                .ExecuteAsync(); // EXCEPTION THROWN HERE
```

So essentially it will store the token into the db, via my api. Now, I have an azure function which needs to read from this db (which it does), and acquire a token if the one required is expired, but I am getting an incorrect audience error.

My problem is, Im not 100% sure this is the correct way of doing this or not.

To clear up:

**Azure App Registrations**

Client App registration (client_id 1)
Api App registration (client_id 2)

**My apps**

Angular (configured with client_id 1)
.NET API (configure with client_id 2)

UPDATE:
The error lies in my azure function here:

```
// Create a GraphServiceClient using the provided access token
            _userClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                    requestMessage =>
                    {
                        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                            new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue(consultantMicrosoftGraphToken.TokenType, consultantMicrosoftGraphToken.AccessToken);

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                )
            );
```

and the error is `Code: InvalidAuthenticationToken Message: Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.`

Comment: The error you are encountering is most likely due to an incorrect audience when trying to acquire a token on behalf of the user. The audience value should be the client ID of the API app registration in Azure, which is client_id 2 in your case. Make sure that the audience value matches the client ID of the API app registration.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. So my first token from client_id 1, has the client_id 2 as the aud, so I think that is correct. The audience issue is when I call `AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf`, any idea why that could be?

Comment: Now the error is that the token is expired which is a different problem in itself as I can't acquire a new token if the last one is expired weirdly

Comment: When you call the AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf method, make sure that you're passing the correct scopes for the API. The scope parameter should include the scope for the API app registration in Azure, which should be in the format api://{client-id}/scope-name.

Comment: Amazing, so I can generate a new token now, but now I get `'Code: InvalidAuthenticationToken
Message: Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.` when I do this...

Comment: ... `// Create a GraphServiceClient using the provided access token
            _userClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                    requestMessage =>
                    {
                        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                            new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue(consultantMicrosoftGraphToken.TokenType, consultantMicrosoftGraphToken.AccessToken);

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                )
            );`

Comment: To resolve this error, you should check that the audience value in the access token matches the identifier URI of the API or resource being accessed. The identifier URI is typically the Application ID URI of the Azure AD app registration for the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via Postman and got below results:***

I created one **API** app registration and added one scope named `access_as_user` same as you like below:

[image]

Now, I registered one client application and added **API permissions** like this:

[image]

I generated **access token** via Postman using authorization code flow like below:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id: <client_app_ID>
grant_type:authorization_code
scope: api://<API_app_ID>/access_as_user Mail.ReadWrite
code: code
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
client_secret: <secret>
```

**Response:**

[image]

Now, I included the above token in assertion and got **access token**  using **`on-behalf-of`** flow successfully like this:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id: <API_app_ID>
client_secret: <API_app_secret>
scope: api://<API_app_ID>/access_as_user Mail.ReadWrite
grant_type: urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
assertion: <paste_token_from_above_request>
requested_token_use: on_behalf_of
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this access token to fetch signed-in user mail box messages, I got **same error** as you like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages
```

**Response:**

[image]

> The error usually occurs if you make calls to API with access token
> having **wrong** audience/scopes.

To read signed-in user mail box, your access token `aud` should be https://graph.microsoft.com  having **Mail.ReadWrite** in `scp` claim.

When I decoded the access token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/), it has **audience** of API application not Microsoft Graph.

[image]

To **resolve** the error, you need to generate access token by changing scope to `Mail.ReadWrite` of Microsoft Graph.

I generated the access token again by changing scope to  `Mail.ReadWrite` using **on-behalf-of** flow via Postman like this:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id: <API_app_ID>
client_secret: <API_app_secret>
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.ReadWrite
grant_type: urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
assertion: <paste_token_from_above_request>
requested_token_use: on_behalf_of
```

**Response:**

[image]

To confirm that, I decoded this access token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/) and got **audience** of Microsoft Graph with  **Mail.ReadWrite** in `scp` claim.

[image]

When I used this access token to read signed-in user mail box, I got **response** successfully like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages
```

**Response:**

[image]

In your case, while acquiring **on-behalf-of** token, make sure to pass scope as https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.ReadWrite to read the user mailbox.

Comment: Incredible! That's solved my issue which i've been stuck on for so long! This answer completely steps through my problem and shows all the issue's that I was having (the aud being my client id was the issue). Thank you so much!