# Refresh expired access token when using OBO Flow

Tags: .net, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

So a couple weeks back I asked this question: [Azure AD AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75601575/azure-ad-acquiretokenonbehalfof)

Essentially I was asking about how to acquire a token of behalf of a user. Now I can do this in Angular. What I need to do is now pass that accessToken to my .NET API which I can do also and acquire a token onBehalfOf.

My issue is when that token expires and I believe MSAL.NET doesn't expose refresh token and the token only last like 2 hours or something.

I'll share my code below for
Acquiring AccessToken

```
  _confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                    .Create(_configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"])
                    .WithAuthority(_configuration["AzureAd:Authority"])
                    .WithClientSecret(_configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"])
                    .WithTenantId(_configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"])
                    .Build();

                var userAssertion = new UserAssertion(accessToken);
                var result = await _confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf(scopes, userAssertion).ExecuteAsync();
                return result;
```

NOTE: my scopes have changed to my original question linked to :

```
 "Mail.ReadWrite",
 "offline_access"
```

Comment: `Refresh expired access token` required a refresh token, but refresh toke is only available for auth code flow.... Just my humble opinion...

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I generated access token using **authorization code flow** by using below parameters:

```json
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/TeantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id: <client_app_ID>
grant_type:authorization_code
scope: api://AppID/test.read Mail.ReadWrite offline_access
code: code
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
client_secret: <secret>
```

[image]

Now, I generated access token by using **`on-behalf-of`** flow like below:

```json
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id: <API_app_ID>
client_secret: <API_app_secret>
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.ReadWrite
grant_type: urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
assertion: <paste_token_from_above_request>
requested_token_use: on_behalf_of
```

[image]

If the access token expires and fails to refresh, then you might get ***"invalid_token"*** error.

> My issue is when that token expires and I believe MSAL.NET doesn't expose refresh token and the token only last like 2 hours or something.

**Note** that: **`MSAL.NET`** refreshes the token within token cache and does not expose any refresh tokens for security reasons.

- Every time a token is generated, MSAL's token cache stores it.
- The token cache contains a refresh token, MSAL additionally refreshes the token when it is about to expire.
- So, there is no need to manage the token expiration on your own.

You can **force the Application to acquire new access token regularly** by setting the value as true.

```cs
result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
             .WithForceRefresh(true)
             .ExecuteAsync();
```

**Reference:**

[High availability · AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet Wiki · GitHub](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/High-availability#pro-active-token-renewal) by Bogdan Gavril