# MSGraph best auth flow for single sign on

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, msal

I am trying to understand the Microsoft Graph authentication flows and what I should use for my application.
It already works, but there are some issues with the current setup, and we are rebuilding it for AWS and I want to have a closer look at how to properly handle the MS Graph auth flow.

Use case:
I am currently building a node.js express API and I would like to add an integration with Microsoft Graph.
So that when a user goes on our portal, they go to calendars and go to the M365 and press add integration.
The user then needs to authenticate once and from then on the calendar can be retrieved.
In order to be used by the devices that are connected to our portal (these devices run our Android app on small tablets).
So the way I would like to retrieve the data is by using webhooks, so we can listen whether a booking is created/modified/deleted and update the data in our database.
Also, we would like this to work for multi-tenant environments.

How I did it so far:
In my current app, I used the following libraries specific for MS Graph:

```
"@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client": "^2.0.0",
"msal": "^1.0.0",
"passport-azure-ad": "^4.2.0",
"simple-oauth2": "^3.1.0",
```

I started by configuring passport with the OIDCStrategy with several env parameters like clientId, identityMetadata, etc together with the signInComplete function.
So the moment the user want to authorize the /auth/signin gets called and uses the `passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect')` together with some parameters to get the login prompt.
This would then request permission to add the Cleverspace azure app to the tenant.
If this is accepted then it would call the /auth/callback method and if everything went successful the signincomplete function is called.
This then creates the oath2 token by using the simple-oauth2 library with the client and auth env parameters.
The function just saves the MS Graph user to our database together with its token.
If the token gets expired, we renew it by using the simple-oauth2 library again and use the .refresh method on the token.

The problem:
Now I wonder if this is still a valid way of authentication, and also if there is a way to handle problems with the signin flow.
Because as of now when the user does the signin process but the grant admin consent flow is disabled they get the message that admin approval is needed.
For some reason when the user would log in with the admin account to add the application to the environment and remove the admin account from the portal to add a non admin account that would retrieve the calendar, yet it seems it doesn't work.
As that account is unable to retrieve any data, I am assuming here that this is because the account used to add the azure application is the account that is needed to get the data from their environment.
Unless I'm doing something wrong or missing something, as of now I have no idea how to properly solve this.

The question:

1. Is my current auth flow valid for my use case or do I need to use a different flow that has Single sign in, because having to log in multiple times to keep the system alive is quite annoying?
2. When I keep the current flow, is there a way to solve the Admin approval issue I'm facing?
3. If a different flow is needed, is the "Need Admin approval" flow still a possible result due to their azure config, and is there a solution to fix my issue in that case?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an Azure AD Application by selecting "
*Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant)* " to support **Multitenant environments**:

[image]

The authentication flow you are implementing is valid. If you do not want users to log in multiple times, then you can implement **On-Behalf-Of** flow. Refer this [**SO Thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75788379/refresh-expired-access-token-when-using-obo-flow) by me.

When I tried to login to the application, ***I got the same error as below:***

[image]

The error ***"Need admin approval"*** usually occurs if the API permissions added to the Azure AD Application has not been granted admin consent.

You must have either Global Administrator, Privileged Role Administrator, or Application Administrator role to grant Admin consent.

*Go to the Azure Portal -> Microsoft Entra ID -> App registrations -> Your App -> API permissions -> Grant Admin Consent*

[image]

**Otherwise**, Grant tenant wide admin consent by using below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/adminconsent?client_id=ClientID
```

And click on **accept**:

[image]

The Admin consent granted to the API permissions:

[image]

**If still the issue persists**, check the below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Enterprise Applications -> Consent and Permissions -> User consent settings*

Set the User consent settings to **`Allow user consent for apps`**:

[image]

Use the **Admin Consent Workflow** if you don't want to grant permission for all users to access the app:

*Go to Enterprise Applications -> Consent and permissions -> Admin consent settings*

[image]

When the user logins, the **Approval Required screen**:

[image]

**Reference:**

[Configure the admin consent workflow - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-admin-consent-workflow)

Comment: @Rukimini oh okay, glad that the current auth flow is fine. I am just wondering I noticed that you use like a direct post request to get the token but that's something that I am not doing as of now I just use passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect') which gives me the oathtoken already and I just refresh the token using simple-oauth2 package. So as far as I can tell I'm not sending any token requests to Microsoft unless they are requesting the token updates? Or is this not a problem?

Comment: No you can do it based on your requirement and that will not cause a issue. I just gave a sample to understand OBO flow.

Comment: oh okay, good to know! Now about the admin consent flow so basically you are saying that there isn't much I can do from my side when a customer gets the "Need admin approval" issue? The only thing I can do is provide proper documentation and hope they do the setup correctly? Because I once had a customer with this issue and they used an admin account, but since the admin account wasn't a delegated user of the resource mailboxes it wasn't capable of getting the information...  I was just hoping that there would be a way to prevent this issue so support isn't necessary every time.

Comment: Did you grant Grant Admin consent to the API permissions? I have provided all the possible workarounds to fix the issue

Comment: @Rukmini I did grant Admin consent but that's for my tenant, If the customer wants to integrate the application will be added to their tenant aswell. That's were the problem starts because if they receive the "Need admin approval" popup the application won't get added and they can't grant admin consent...

Comment: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/adminconsent?client_id=ClientID` Please use this endpoint and login as Global Admin and check if still the issue persists

Comment: @Rukmini in my own organization/tenant it works fine I can grant the permissions without any issues, but if our customer goes to our app portal and add integration to M365 their configuration is sometimes different and because of security reasons they disable the grant admin consent for normal users. They aren't always willing to change those settings thus resulting in them contacting us for this problem and me having to spend my afternoon trying to explain to a security company they have to enable it if they want their service account to be able to integrate M365 with our product.

Comment: @Rukmini that's why I said that you were basically saying that these configuration steps need to be done by the customer to allow our azure app to be added to their environment in the first place.

Comment: Yes I agree with you if they are disabling it then the users will face the error

Comment: In that case I have accepted your solution, I am glad that I am on the right track now! Thanks you for your help!

Comment: @SPT I was already planning on accepting this answer as the solution, but I just wanted some further clarification, so no worries I ain't ungrateful towards people who help each other!

Comment: @BillyCottrell When I tried to login to app with another tenant user I dint face any issue as there were no security implementations done in that tenant. Check this if helpful https://damienbod.com/2023/01/02/azure-ad-multi-tenant-azure-app-registration-consent/

Comment: this confirms that I am unable to change this from my side and that it's the customers responsibility. I can only give them the proper information to do the setup as needed.