# Azure ad login does not work with custom scopes - Invalid User Info Response

Tags: spring-security, azure-active-directory, spring-cloud-gateway

I have this setup where the login works.

```
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          azure-active-directory:
            issuer-uri: ${OAUTH2_ISSUER}
        registration:

          api-gateway:
            provider: azure-active-directory
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
            client-id: ${OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID}
            client-secret: ${OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET}
            scope: openid
```

However when i switch the scope to a custom one which just created before in azure ad

```
scope: api://my-id-removed/jango-test-api
```

I end up on a login?error route after logging in. And in the logs I can see that there is a problem with the user info endpoint

```
2023-10-10T00:51:24.151+02:00 DEBUG 50489 --- [ctor-http-nio-7] athPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher : Checking match of request : '/login/oauth2/code/azure'; against '/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}'
2023-10-10T00:51:25.078+02:00 DEBUG 50489 --- [ctor-http-nio-6] o.s.s.w.s.a.AuthenticationWebFilter      : Authentication failed: [invalid_user_info_response] An error occurred reading the UserInfo response: [invalid_user_info_response]
```

When I visit the user info endpoin in the browser

https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo

I get the following error

```
{
"error": {
"code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
"message": "Access token is empty.",
"innerError": {
"date": "2023-10-09T22:58:11",
"request-id": "7e7a3bc8-7fb5-4bdb-a648-bfd4bf6f2dc8",
"client-request-id": "7e7a3bc8-7fb5-4bdb-a648-bfd4bf6f2dc8"
}
}
}
```

Comment: Note that, `/userinfo` endpoint calls **Microsoft Graph** to fetch user claims that works with **`openid`** scope only. You cannot call it with token generated with custom scope. Refer this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/userinfo#calling-the-userinfo-endpoint).

Comment: Ok i understood, but spring security just calls it. How can I then not call it? This explains why the login works with the openid scope but fails when I use a custom scope

Comment: You cannot generate single token with multiple different scopes (Microsoft graph and custom scopes). Alternatively, you can make use of **on-behalf flow** that calls custom API initially and then calls Microsoft Graph later. Refer these threads if helpful [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75601575/azure-ad-acquiretokenonbehalfof/75647649#75647649) [link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/ms-identity-docs-code-java/ms-identity-docs-code-webapi-obo-java/)

Comment: There is no other alternative? I dont care about user-info or then openid scope. All I want to do is call my microservice which is a OAUTH resource server. 
And to protect it I need to use a custom-scope. The default token I get with openid has a invalid signature. So i created a custom scope.

Answer (score 0):

> Note that, `/userinfo` endpoint calls **Microsoft Graph** to fetch user claims that works with token having **`openid`** scope only.

I registered one Azure AD application and exposed an API with **custom scope** as below:

[image]

In the application, I added below **API permissions** and granted admin consent to them:

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** using authorization code flow via Postman with **custom scope** like this:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type:authorization_code
client_id:appID
client_secret:secret
scope: api://d7e1d003-a9da-45f6-b9c1-287cd3fd93a3/jango-test-api
code:code
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to run `/userinfo` endpoint, I got **error** like this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo
```

**Response:**

[image]

The error occurred as the token does not have **Microsoft Graph** audience with **`openid`** permission.

You can **confirm** that by decoding the token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) and check **`aud`** & **`scp`** claims:

[image]

To **resolve** the error, I generated the access token using authorization code flow with **`openid`** scope via Postman like this:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id:appID
client_secret:secret
scope: openid
code:code
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to run `/userinfo` endpoint, I got **response** successfully as below:

```
 GET https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Microsoft identity platform UserInfo endpoint - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/userinfo#calling-the-userinfo-endpoint)

Comment: Hi @JangoCG, is there something else that I can help you with? You cannot call Microsoft Graph API with access token generated with  **custom scopes**. To call  `/userinfo`  endpoint, token `aud` scope must be  [graph.microsoft.com](https://graph.microsoft.com/). That's the default behavior.

Comment: Hi @Sridveri. Yes, I dont want to call it all to be honest. I just want to protect my microservice which as OAUTh Resource. ALl Iam trying to achieve here with this OAUTH Client is to get an access token, with which I can call my other micrservice

Comment: Hi @JangoCG I understood that earlier you tried to get the access token with scope “openid” which is Microsoft graph permission, and you will be able to call /userinfo endpoint which is MS graph endpoint.

Comment: However, to call the protected API from your client app using OAuth2, you need to provide scope of your API while requesting the token and that access token will be used to call your **protected API** (microservice endpoint) **only** (not any other APIs like MS Graph through that access token).