Azure AD token for accessing Graph token
I need to access Microsoft Graph API using my API Scope and Audience.
I need to be able to acquire a token on behalf of a user in my API, using the token I received in my client mobile application. I have used MSAL package in Android and iOS to get the token from my client app registration in Azure.
I need to access multiple Graph resources.
Using Android and iOS native SDKs
Android SDK
iOS SDK
Audience

Scope

Whenever I try to hit the API (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me) I get message stating Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.


You need pass that API token as assertion value in on-behalf of flow and generate token again to call Microsoft Graph API as I mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75601575/azure-ad-acquiretokenonbehalfof

The error usually occurs if you are trying to access Microsoft Graph with token generated with exposed API Scope and Audience.
Initially, I too got same error when I tried to call Microsoft Graph with token generated with custom API scope as below:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me


To resolve the error, generate token using on-behalf of flow by passing above API token as assertion value.
In my case, I used below .NET code to acquire token using on-behalf flow and called Microsoft Graph API successfully like this:
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var scopes = new[] { "User.Read" };
        var tenantId = "tenantId";
        var clientId = "appId";
        var clientSecret = "secret";
        var apitoken = "token_with_api_scope";

        var onBehalfOfCredential = new OnBehalfOfCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, apitoken);
        var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(scopes);

        // Get the token
        var token = await onBehalfOfCredential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext, new CancellationToken());

        // Print the token to the console
        Console.WriteLine($"Access Token: {token.Token}");

        // Use HttpClient to call Graph API
        using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", tokenResult.Token);

        var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me");
        Console.WriteLine("\n API Response:");
        Console.WriteLine(response);
    }
}

Response:

Reference:
.net - Azure AD AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf - Stack Overflow by me
